# How to create new folder using contextual menu in MAC OS?

Tags: shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I want to create a short cut to create new folder from the right-click/contextual menu in Mac Mavericks. What is the procedure to do so?

Comment: Isn't my question relevant? Why is it being down-voted?

Comment: You need to click in a space. Can't be done 'on top' of any existing file/folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know some people prefer the mouse, but as an alternative for completeness sake...

Of if you prefer SHIFT-COMMAND-N in any window (including right on the desktop) will create a new folder right there.

Answer (score -1):

When you right click on the desktop or a Finder window the first menu item should be "New Folder", just select that.